# MySQL Performance: update vs outer join

Tags: mysql, performance, outer-join

I am a bit puzzled: I understand that the general experience is that outer joins are fast. Well, my case here is different:
Need to add one field from the sds table to the drug table, based on one common key field:

```
select drug.*, sds.name 
from drug
left outer join sds 
on drug.id = sds.id;
```

Table sizes:
drug       25,000 rows
sds        65,000 rows
matching   24,000 rows on field "id"
Both tables are indexed on the id field

The first query above did not return a result after 2 minutes, then I aborted.

So I redid the query with a temporary table:

```
create temporary table tmp select *, space( 50) as name from drug;
create index id on tmp ( id);
update tmp, sds 
    set tmp.name = sds.name 
    where tmp.id = sds.id;
```

All this together took less than one second cpu time.

Does this make sense? she we avoid outer joins like the plague?

Comment: Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE for both tables.  It is unusual to JOIN on `id` since `id` is usually a separate `PRIMARY KEY` for each table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good explanation of INNER vs OUTER joins.  You will see each has it place but they have trade offs too.

[What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)

After reading your question again... I really think you should be looking at an INNER JOIN as you stated 24,000 matching rows.

```
SELECT 
  d.*, 
  s.name 
FROM 
  drug d INNER JOIN sds s on d.id = s.id;
```

This should only return the 24,000 rows that match and be much faster because you are excluding rows from both tables on query.

Comment: if you use aliases `d` and `s` you need to call fields `d.*` `s.name`? Don't we?

Comment: That link is good for standard SQL.  For MySQL, `INNER` and `OUTER` and `CROSS` are ignored; `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `ON` and `WHERE` determine whether it is INNER or OUTER or CROSS.  `FULL` does not exist, though you can achieve it with a UNION.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check (I don't see any reason to use **outer**):

```
select drug.*, sds.name 
from drug
left join sds 
on drug.id = sds.id;
```

Comment: Alex is correct, OUTER joins have a very specific usage and can cause issue when used incorrectly.  Chances are a LEFT join will yield the result you are looking for and will be faster.

Comment: In MySQL, the keyword `OUTER` is ignored.

Comment: give me a link to where it is written

Comment: I understand that `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` are synonymous; so, no change here. I did rerun the query with `LEFT JOIN` tough and still did not get a result within 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The sql does not specify if a left or right outer join is to be used, thus the default is for a full outer join.  The sql will then return the union of drug and sds, i.e. all the rows in drug and all the rows in sds.

In terms of a Venn diagram, the inner joins generally will give you the parts of the diagram that are intersecting.

A very detailed look at joins:
[What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)